# Is there a way to open/read .PRI files? (package resource index - used in Windows Store apps)

Tags: windows, resources, microsoft-metro, compiled

I need to take some resources from **SOURCE.PRI** file, modify certain values, then create **TARGET.PRI** file, which has the exact same content as **SOURCE.PRI**, except the modified values mentioned above.

There are a couple of **PRI** file extensions, I am referring to the compiled resource files used by Windows Store apps ([more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694557.aspx)).

I am assuming that, since **.PRI** files are already compiled, there is no way to read them, character by character, with simple text parser.

Therefore, I am looking for a way to compile and decompile the **.PRI** file.

Did anyone find a way to do this?

Comment: The format is undocumented.  You can decompile them with `makepri.exe dump`

Comment: i know about the makepri.exe , but am I allowed to use this if i have a custom application that I am going to sell to clients?

Comment: No, it is not a distributable component.  You'll need to write this off as a viable strategy if this is supposed to happen at runtime.  Pretty unclear why you are contemplating this btw, you can't even get write access to the directory.

Comment: `MakePri.exe dump /if C:\MyApp\resources.pri`

Answer (score 7):

In [this github project](https://github.com/PFCKrutonium/Windows-10-Login-Background-Changer) they edited the **.pri** file in order to change the logon screen.

You can try and look what they did there and how to accomplish that with your own project.

*Although it's been a long time since the question was asked, I think it's still good to have an answer here that will guide anyone who's interested in doing that and arrived here.*

Answer (score 2):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/makepri-exe-command-options#dump-command

You can use the makepri.exe tool itself to dump the contents in to an xml format.

You can also open it in a text editor and somewhat make out the contents, though most of it is in binary.